# How to convert 24 hr String time into 12 hr time String format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have time in NSString like "15:15"

I want to covert this NSString time into 12 hr NSString(i.e "3:15 PM").

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter` to turn the string in a `NSDate`. Then use the dateformatter again to change the `NSDate` to a string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15:15"];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
NSString *pmamDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Code might contain some errors, written without compiling or testing.

Comment: Just be sure to set the formatter's locale to en_US_POSIX before starting.

Comment: can you tell me how to set it?

Comment: Thanks . Working code for me.      NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
     timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
    
    txtTime.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:myTimePickerView.date];

Comment: like +1 simple and sweet answer

Answer (score 2):

@python

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this SO question: [NSDateFormatter dateFromString and iPhone in 24 Hour Format Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173965/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-and-iphone-in-24-hour-format-confusion)

You should be able to use to use `NSDateFormatter` to format the style of time you want, then read in the string to the formatter and pull it back out in your desired format.