# NSDateFormatter doesn't allow 24-hour format

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have to display the **date** in my app, where i need to display that only in the format of `12 - hour format`, i have used this code to display the `date`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:kDateDisplayFormat];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *todaysDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
[[self lblPointsDate] setText:todaysDate];
```

here when i change my iPhone date format to 24-hour it display's in 24-hour format. I need to **convert** 24-hour to 12-hour format or make it **display only in 12-hour format**. How can i do this?

Comment: Please post you `kDateDisplayFormat`, also I would suggest never to use a static format, but use the `NSDateFormatterStyle`

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139973/how-to-convert-24-hr-string-time-into-12-hr-time-string-format

Comment: #define kDateDisplayFormat          @"dd.M.yyyy / hh a"

Comment: You are using a correct format `hh` should give you 12-hour format.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]` WHY???

Comment: Actually it will be like :    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date is  :"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]

Comment: When you change your iPhone 12/24 setting you break things.  The 12/24 instruction in the setDateFormat operand are ignored.  To get around this you must change the locale, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735644/581994).  Of course, if you WANT the iPhone setting to "show through", use a generic format rather than rigidly specifying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just switch

```
kDateDisplayFormat.dateFormat = @"HH:mm a";
```

to

```
kDateDisplayFormat.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
```

Comment: I'm using small "hh" only

Answer (score 2):

Although a solution is to use the 12-hour time format `hh` and not te 24-hour `HH` format why not let the user systems preference select the correct format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

self.lblPointsDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]
```

Also there is no need to set the `dateFormatter.timeZone` to the system timezone, this is set by default.

Comment: The dateFormat you post is correct, can you post a log where print out the date and the result of the dateFormatter?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
NSString *theTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```