# Convert date-time in 12hrs format to 24hrs format in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

`2015-05-29 06:10 PM` convert this date into system timezone 24hrs formate

convert this date into `2015-05-29 18:10:00`

Comment: you should read NSDateFormatter class

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate time converting from 12hr to 24 hr format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395832/nsdate-time-converting-from-12hr-to-24-hr-format)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dateFromString and iPhone in 24 Hour Format Confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173965/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-and-iphone-in-24-hour-format-confusion)

Comment: I already check this ans but not solve problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to convert 12 hour format date into 24 hours date.

```
NSDate *date = your date in 12 hours format;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"];
NSString *dateStringInTwentyHours = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

You can use this code snippet to convert 12 hour to 24 hour format.

```
        let sourceDateString = "2015-05-29 10:40 AM"
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
        let date = formatter.date(from: sourceDateString)
        print("\(date)")

        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

        let strDate = formatter.string(from: date!)
        print(strDate)
```